# How to validate the grid table value in protractor?

Tags: grid, protractor

In protractor, I want to verify whether added value is displaying in the grid.
How do I validate it?

The grid looks like this:

[image: grid]

Comment: Provide html code

Comment: Thanks @kishanpatel ..it was quiet big.. please see the code snippet here...i was thinking to use the ng-repeat but not very sure how to use the same .. https://pastebin.com/N96kuWu5

Comment: Just provide me html for the grid.

Comment: ok..the grid html is here - https://pastebin.com/zcZ1JZ1d

Comment: Can you provide me website link ? What is your scenario ? Adding a value in the grid and then verify that value is added or not?

Comment: the website is internal one. it cannot be accessed outside the VM. I am adding a entry to a module and then verifying the module grid to make sure the value is added in the grid table

Comment: if you have time now, i can do a screenshare. can you let me know your id to ping?

Comment: What I see from your html code, There is no difference obtained between the grid rows. Also The rows which you added i.e. `Ankush Bhatia` all values are same. Will it happen in real? I want a unique value in each row   .  Are you getting me? How can all 3 rows have identical values?

Comment: yes i got it. there is no validation happening here. i can add duplicate entries with same name.so, should i ask developer to put validation?

Comment: other than validation, if i want to capture the text of a row how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it at your end and let me know it works:

```
var a  = element(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'test_protractor')]")).getText().then(function(msg){
  console.log(msg)
  expect(msg).toEqual("test_protractor")
})
```

> If there are multiple and you want to get only first row then

```
var a  = element.all(by.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'test_protractor')]")).get(1).getText().then(function(msg){
  console.log(msg)
  expect(msg).toEqual("test_protractor")
})
```

Comment: for example, the grid has 5 different row entries and i want to put a for loop is it possible?

Comment: Yes just make a loop and instead of get(1) use get(i)

Comment: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: Welcome :-) @kav

Comment: if you have time please take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109914/run-conf-ts-in-vs-2013-ts  i am really stuck with this for more than a week

Comment: kishan, is it possible to put a loop for all the elements in the master obligation name column? i want to check like, put a loop and the name is matched, it should come out. is it possible in that way?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use `element.all` and then filter it out as per your wish. It is a good approach

Comment: You can share your html code. First you try . And if you are stuck, I'll help you out.

Comment: kishan, the html code is here. it has row html and column html and individual column value html - https://pastebin.com/GBP3AZNQ i tried something like this but not successful.   - https://pastebin.com/4aRTR6Ak can you help me out

Comment: It is difficult to understand the html code you have provided.
My simplest suggestion will be using `element.all` try to find out row first then go for columns. While Selecting a locator make sure all elements(rows and columns) are getting selected.

Comment: `element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding']")).getText().then(function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
})` What is printed in console ?

Comment: i will give a try now and tel you

Comment: kishan, it printed all the row details

Comment: this is actually great..but i want to verify for a particular row name say i want to make sure whether test123 is present or not...how to do that?

Comment: should i use expect?  expect().toContain("test"); like this?

Comment: i want to verify the masterobligationname column entries.

Comment: Look if it is giving you more data we can always be on safer side . You just use expect and verify whatever you want. Put 3-4 expects to make your test case validate more.

Comment: You have provided me old html code . Provide me for this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY5os.png

Comment: the code is same only - https://pastebin.com/NNSVuikS  when i tried to put expect,  var allvalue = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding']")).getText().then(function (msg) {

            expect(allvalue).toContain("test123");  it says, expected undefined to contain 'test123'; but this will not validate against the specific column right

Comment: `element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='ui-grid-cell-contents ng-scope ng-binding']")).getText().then(function (msg) { expect(msg).toContain("test123");` This is the correct way. The promise is returning you the text so keep `expect` within the promise

Comment: ok right..thanks for the help kishan..very kind of you to take your time on this

Comment: I have added @kav

Comment: Yes . Enjoy :-) have a great day ahead

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you have created a new row with below details,

```
var newRow = {
  "obligation_name" : "sudharsan",
  "status" : "",
  "module" : "Test Module"
}
```

If you want to verify that the newly entered row is displayed,You can try the below code,

```
var rowList = element.all(by.repeater("(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns"));
var expectedRow = rowList.filter(function(rowElement,index) {
  var columnList = rowElement.all(by.css("div.ui-grid-cell-contents"));
  return columnList.getText().then(function(columnValues) {
    return (columnValues[0]== newRow["obligation_name"]) && (columnValues[1] == newRow["status"]) && (columnValues[2] == newRow["module"]);
  });
});
expect(expectedRow.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: thanks sudharshan. I will give a try and let you know

Comment: sudharsan, even though the value is added to grid, error is occuring. - error says, expected 0 to be greater than 0

Comment: @kavitha, 0 is not greater than 0, as the expectedRow.count() is 0