# run conf.ts in VS 2013 + TS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, protractor

i want to run the conf.ts in visual studio 2013 with type script. i have added the conf.ts, spec.ts and required typing. it looks as below.

There are 0 build errors. if i run the conf.ts, it is going to local host which is mentioned in the project properties and not to the base path have mentioned in the spec.ts. how to resolve this issue?

[project in VS 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6akY.png)

Comment: So basically it is not calling the baseurl  mentioned in conf.js ?

Comment: yes right.it is going to http://localhost:51887/ which is mentioned in project properties. If i change the local host to my url in project properties, it is throwing error.

Comment: Please share your `mo.ts` file as well!

Comment: ram, attached the mo.ts -https://pastebin.com/EzHsb8Kw when i run, it is not going to browser.get url mentioned in mo.ts

Comment: what error is it throwing? ideally when you given a `baseUrl` you should append the pages in your tests/scripts, to avoid any confusion. That is the primary usage of baseUrl

Comment: no error; when i click on run in the VS, it is going to localhost. i dont know what all settings needed to run the conf file directly. what am i missing here?

Comment: Ram Pasala : Where can I get the best material to learn Advance Protractor?

Comment: @KishanPatel hey any update on this? I am still stuck in configuring the VS for the protractor... what is the ide you are using to run your protractor scripts?